# Will the Stack Overflow editor ever get better?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor

The editor for Stack Overflow just doesn't seem to be functional for editing bigger blocks of code. At the very least it would be nice to have a block indent/unindent feature.

As a sidenote, could the whole Stack Exchange network please find a different key to use for linking? Some people use <kbd>appl-L</kbd> to highlight the URL bar in Chrome/Safari, and I know there are alternatives (I'm certain this has to bother the superuser crowd exceptionally).

This question has been asked to some extent here, but I am more than just asking, I am making a case for upgrading, so please don't immediately mark this as a duplicate.

If there are plans on the roadmap for a better editor, when will the delivery date be?

If there aren't:

Stack Overflow, and the SE network in general, is about having a premium Q/A sites. A lot of users, myself included, and new users in particular, are willing to sacrifice the formatting of their code because using a boiler-plate HTML `textarea` is too much work, especially with 10+ lines.

Encouraging people to add code to their questions is good for Stack Overflow. More code means more content, and more search engine indexing.

Some features that seem almost necessary:

1. Block Indent
2. Block Unindent
3. Consistent paste behavior, perhaps automated formatting?

**--EDIT--**

While I appreciate that I could paste in code from my editor (and I often do), sometimes the code from my editor is indented already, and it doesn't paste into the text area correctly. As a fairly frequent reviewer, I **always** see edits that merely fix the formatting of the code. For something so simple, wouldn't it be worth it to encourage users to format their code properly? Could it be possible to have a feature that allows you to auto-format any section you write into a code block?

Comment: So don't use a boiler-plate HTML text area. Use your favorite editor that has all the features you want, and copy/paste into your answer here.

Comment: I totally agree this would be useful to have, preferably as an option in your preferences so people don't have to worry about opting out. Saying 'just copy it to another editor' is a bit close-minded for a site that is supposed to have programmers who are usually required to think outside the box. Thinking outside this editbox isn't really what I prefer in those cases. It just seems like unneeded extra effort

Comment: @KenWhite except when, in lots of cases, all the features I want are tab indentation and the ability to enter text. That's really all I would like to have, when writing simple small bits of code.

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I don't have much to complain about with the current editor. It's easy enough to write up my code in my favorite text editor (Sublime Text, Notepad++, etc) or IDE, copy and paste that into the text area, highlight the whole thing, and hit <kbd>CTRL+K</kbd> to indent it as a code block.

Or I just do the indentation in my editor before pasting into the text area, so that hitting <kbd>CTRL+K</kbd> is unnecessary.

Comment: I guess although that would work, what if you want to redact code that is irrelevant to the question? Now I have to open a new file, paste and edit my code in there, then past it to stackoverflow, and then what if I want to change it?

Comment: @BrianWheeler if I have to do that much work to edit a post, I'm usually copying and pasting the whole thing into a text editor anyways.

Comment: Call me lazy, but it seems like a lot of steps for a place where all of the software developers in the world congregate and share knowledge, can't we build something better?

Comment: @BrianWheeler The idea is that this is a place to get help with code that *you've already written*. You really shouldn't have to use Stack Overflow's post area for writing code. It should be as simple as copy-and-paste or, if you need to fix something, you'd ideally be making those fixes in the place where they actually matter (your text editor/IDE). I'm not saying that the post area couldn't be better, but it really doesn't *need* to be. If you're running into trouble with keyboard shortcuts and such, you should get more of a feel for Markdown so that you can write posts more quickly.

Comment: @BrianWheeler Yes I think you have a case here, but on the other hand, it's so obviously true that probably there's a reason why this didn't happen so far. Code snippets are a half-hearted attempt. Somehow it seems to be hard to improve this part of the site. Not that I wouldn't love to hear why...

Answer (score 8):

> The editor for Stack Overflow just doesn't seem to be functional for editing bigger blocks of code.

Well, you shouldn't be writing "bigger blocks of code". Save that for your real project.

Here you should be posting [minimal testcases](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I see no reason to encourage the opposite.

Comment: I think it's not fair to jump to the word 'bigger'. Later the OP says `10+ lines`. That's hardly a wall of code. The question is not primarily about size, it's about quality. (That said, who can answer this question anyway?).

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote [Better Stack Exchange](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-stack-exchange/ohgloaohphplfbdcbkoobcmbjopjbhnl), which lets you use a modified Code Mirror editor. It supports all indentation stuff you want and much, much more (automatic lists, inline markdown, etc.)

P.S., I'm acually using it to write this answer! :D

---

Original SlackApps post: [Better Stack Exchange - awesome new text editor and UI improvements](https://stackapps.com/questions/6926/better-stack-exchange-awesome-new-text-editor-and-ui-improvements)