# Markdown editor indent and outdent functionality

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor

### No tab key support

It has been a while for me here on Stack Overflow, and from the beginning of my experience I've noticed something which still leaves a bad taste in my mouth when I create and edit posts: **in the current Markdown editor there's no support for the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key**.

This isn't only related to Stack Overflow (obviously), it concerns all the Stack Exchange sites, although Stack Overflow users are the ones who suffer the most for this because of the enormous amount of short or long code snippets which get posted and edited every day by everyone.

It often happens that, when writing a code snippet, **if I want to indent or dedent several lines of code I have to move the caret at the beginning of each line and manually add four spaces**, and let's say it, this is just boring and time wasting. Despite the fact that I prefer tab (`\t`) characters, I understand that tabs may not always be rendered the same way, and it's better to use spaces for code snippets, but as of now, it's a real pain to always have to hit that spacebar thousand of times every day while writing posts.

#### Background research

I'm not posting another duplicated question here on meta, I've already seen someone trying to bring this feature request to the attention of Stack Exchange developers. Some examples of this are the following questions:

- [Why does tab key not work while writing questions/answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255953)
- [Preferences option to enable tab-key space inserting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273019)
- [Is there a way to indent a chunk of code? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284967)
- [Will the Stack Overflow editor ever get better?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268669)

But unfortunately looks like this feature request has always been rejected. For example, quoting from the most upvoted [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255954/3889449) I've found (emphasis mine):

> General internet browser convention dictates that the tab key be used to cycle between various controls on the page, and not to represent the `\t` character, even when a text input control has focus.

> For the site to fight **this would be both somewhat difficult**, because the browser is designed to *not* do what you are asking of it, **and also violates the user expectation of this virtually ubiquitous web browser feature**.  While this may be *possible*, it's generally not a very good idea. [...]

Now, I understand that the real behavior of the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key should be to cycle between page controls and input fields, but **that's a feature worth a submission form (some page with a good amount of input fields), and not a page containing a single main `<textarea>`**.

Many programming sites already implement this by default, and **we, as developers, generally *expect* the tab key to behave like this**, being used to IDEs and text editors which support this feature by default. I personally hit the tab key several times a day while editing answers without thinking about it and always ending up being teleported at the bottom of the page, in the edit summary or tag field, having to scroll back to the top.

### My proposal

Implementing tab characters (`\t`) is not a good idea, and that's ok. This although doesn't mean that we cannot implement four-spaces indentation with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.

To make these Markdown editors much more powerful and smart, **I propose to implement a switchable <kbd>TAB</kbd> indentation functionality**. It would basically be just a little button, nothing cumbersome, something similar to this:

[image: example]

<sup>Image edited by me</sup>

The user will simply toggle the functionality from that little button, and will be able to:

- Indent by 4 spaces at the current caret position pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>;
- Dedent by 4 spaces (if they're present) at the current caret position pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>;
- Indent multiple lines of code by 4 spaces selecting them and pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>;
- Dedent multiple lines of code by 4 spaces selecting them and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

**Here's a visual example** of what I'm talking about:

[image: example]

<sup>GIF created by me using [ScreenToGif v1.4.1](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/)</sup>

Now I think you probably understand why **this would be really significant when talking about very long snippets of code with multiple nested indented blocks**.

### My personal solution

As a personal solution I created a little JavaScript script called `textarea-devtab.js`, which you can test **[here](http://codepen.io/MeBeiM/pen/ogrmBP/)**. It basically implements this small but very useful feature on any children textarea of the chosen `Element`. If you want, you can easily add this to your [Chrome devtools code snippets](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets) and run it whenever you need (as I personally do at the moment).

Simple as this, you can:

```js
// Enable it on any element's children textareas
myElement.enableTextareaDevTab();

// Disable it at any moment
myElement.disableTextareaDevTab();

// Enable it for any textarea of the page
document.body.enableTextareaDevTab();
```

It's just sixty lines of code so I don't see the need of any copyright/license/attribution, I just wanted to share it with my fellow programmers here on Stack Overflow :)

---

**I would like to give a boost to this post** so that Stack programmers will notice it as soon as possible.

## Could we have this beautiful feature?

Comment: I think this would be better asked over on http://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen perhaps some Moderator will migrate it if they find this question more suitable for the SE Meta. I asked here because this is the main SE site which will benefit from this feature, and SE Meta posts don't always get enough attention when being only related to programming sites.

Comment: I don't disagree with you one bit. I would love to see this feature. However, the meta Stack Exchange site deals more with the software behind SO, MSO, etc.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts

Comment: I thoroughly agree with this and I had made a similar JavaScript to help myself out. Yours it nicer though :P

Comment: Ctrl + Tab is the normal way to override default behaviour. That's how you enter tab into a dialog box's edit control and has been the standard for decades.

Comment: @Serenity Chome changes browser tabs on Ctrl+Tab, so most other browsers do. What decades-old standard are you talking about?

Comment: @Serenity: Note that at least on Windows, Ctrl-Tab has been the shortcut to switch dialog box tabs since 95 or before. It is therefore not reliably available for this use, and indeed I am not aware of it working in dialog boxes at all. (Ctrl-Enter, yes.) Any UI convention that does not exist on Windows is not "**the** standard".

Comment: I'm not sure what the "⌘+TAB for Macs users" is noting. We crazy OS X users still just use Tab and Shift+Tab for indenting/unindenting. :)

Comment: @AlexisKing totally forgot Mac users have a shift key too, removed that.

Comment: We crazy Mac users also use ⌘+[ and ⌘+] for indenting and un-indenting. Thanks Xcode!

Comment: Aside: note that the [data.se] editor _does_ indent and dedent with Tab / Shift+Tab. This is a good thing, and would do well to be ported over to the SE markdown editor.

Comment: @senshin Agreed (though it does annoyingly only indent by 2 spaces!)

Comment: I've always wondered why do many sites indent by two spaces.. it's just not enough to distinguish indented code blocks at first sight.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I prefer 4, others prefer 2. The code snippet editor also prefers 2. I guess it's all a nature vs nurture thing. Did you first start with 4 spaces? With no evidence to support me, I would guess that older languages used 2 spaces due to screen space being a premium.

Comment: @DavidG personally, I've always used the tab `\t` character for indentation, it's faster and flexible, and any user who's looking at your code in his own IDE can change the amount of indentation represented by a tab character to whatever he wants, without breaking the original indentation. By the way I do understand that code snippets are better to be written using spaces for indentation, and I prefer four spaces.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli A couple of years ago I would probably have agreed with you, but I think modern IDEs are powerful/clever enough to not care either way what the source file contains.

Comment: This is has been my only major issue with the interaction with this site.  I spent a lot time on DaniWeb before coming here and being able to Tab and Shift+Tab was such a nice feature in the mark down editor.  Lately what I have resorted to is either use my IDE or do 4 spaces copy them and then I can use Ctrl+V to act as a tab.

Comment: My major issue has always been the `\`` character for code blocks (especially in comments), which is not standard in the italian keyboard, and I always have to copy/paste it from somewhere else.

Comment: Related(?): [Stack Overflow users' preference for TABs vs. spaces](https://twitter.com/PeterMortensen/status/585916586357297152).

Comment: Giving this a bump, since I was going to ask for this functionality myself. Tab to indent > tab to go to next input field. I can't believe someone seriously mentioned Windows 95 as a concern for breaking UX conventions - those things shouldn't be near a live internet connection, even if they could load a modern webpage without having an epileptic fit.

Comment: I'm sad that this hasn't happened yet!

Comment: Yeah, me too... :(

Comment: Yes, yes, a thousand times yes!  Every single time I'm editing code in SO, I hit the TAB key, only to find myself somewhere else on the page (and the editor completely offscreen).  Note that the web-based IDEs all use TAB for indentation (and SHIFT-TAB to outdent), so "web standard TAB behavior" is a specious argument against.  The CTRL-K behavior is hardly a replacement, what with all the quirks (one-level indent only, spurious blank lines added when indenting, etc).

Comment: Since a month ago, lack of tab key indentation in QA looks much more strange, as Documentation became public with this feature! Why don't SO developers "back-port" it to the main QA site?

Comment: So, it's 2019 and this feature has not yet seen the light of day. Any site developer ever even commented this thread?

Comment: Google Gmail hasn't even fixed this. I press tab and it tries to send the message.

Comment: The first [CodePen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePen) link (near *"a little JavaScript script"*) is (effectively) broken: *"Pen Not Found"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen not sure what happened there, I removed the link.

Comment: Hey @MarcoBonelli , I used your code (converted it to TypeScript) and made a browser extension that hooks it into stack overflow automatically. The extension is uploaded to the firefox app store [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-overflow-rich-tabbing/), and the source code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/NathanC/Stack-Overflow-Intentation-Extension). It works for Chrome too, but I haven't uploaded it to the Chrome App Store. My usage of your code can be [found here](https://github.com/NathanC/Stack-Overflow-Intentation-Extension/blob/main/src/textareaDev.ts). :)

Answer (score 181):

Yes, please!

We are **developers** - we basically *expect* <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent code and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to unindent it.

This could be implemented on programming-related sites only (SO, Programmers, Code Review, Programming Puzzles) if you think it'd confuse users on other sites - but it'll feel natural to programmers.

I'd go as far as saying this feature should be on by default, and I don't see the point in being able to switch it off. The current behavior feels like editing code in *notepad*, while we could get something like, say, *Notepad++* instead.

Moreover, many people over here don't even know they can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for basic indentation support, and the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (indent when not indented, unindent when indented) is confusing in the first place - mainly because it diverges from what we expect from <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Also, it doesn't allow to indent more than once so it's useless for reformatting parts of code.

Comment: Note: you can always add a fake initial line so that the behaviour of `Ctrl+K` or the `{}` button is indent instead of dedent. Although it requires adding a fake line and then removing it.

Comment: While we're at it, I often hit [Ctrl]+[s] to save the current state of my question/answer. It's silly, I know, because the site already does save the state. But it's even sillier to get that "save page" dialog of the browser. That's really annoying. Who would save a edit-page anyway?

Comment: @stefan: Try Vim.  jk:x

Comment: @Kevin I have to use vim way too often. Luckily this does not affect my keyboard usage habits. (It's awkward enough to do the [Ctrl]+[S] and use [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[C] in browsers just because you're about to paste something into a terminal and you're about to hit [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[V]. That's two very annoying things I won't get rid of too soon). So, no, thank you, I don't want to use vim as my default text editor.

Comment: I totally support having this feature, and I agree with turning it on by default only for the programming sites and off by default for the others, but there should be a button to toggle it on and off on all sites if for no better reason than consistency between sites. A better reason for doing that, of course, is to allow users the choice of having it on or off no mater which site they're on in the SE network.

Comment: Ctrl-K also doesn't work for code in a list item which needs to be `(depth of list item + 1) * 4` spaces deep to work. Same with Blockquote

Comment: So... when is this going to work ?

Answer (score 12):

There's an excellent [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts) that adds tab support to answer text edit fields. I installed it with TamperMonkey for Chrome, and it works great!

Comment: There's also an [alternative script](http://stackapps.com/questions/5038/se-like-i-like-it-userscript) which handles things differently (and has indent on enter support).

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Better Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/6926/better-stack-exchange-awesome-new-text-editor-and-ui-improvements) (Google Chrome Extension). It swaps out the default text editor that Stack Exchange uses with a modified version of SimpleMDE.

Therefore, it supports indentation, inline code blocks, markdown, and all the other stuff you'd expect to be included by default. `:)`

*Shameless plug: I wrote this extension, and I'm using it to write this answer!*

---

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, could I suggest <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (right bracket) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (left bracket), respectively?

**Advantages**

- Allows <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to keep their current behaviour
- Same shortcuts used by other editors such as Atom, Ace, and Gmail
- Currently unused

**Disadvantages**

- A bit obscure

Comment: Those key commands are used on some platforms (macOS, at least) to mean forward / back (in the browser). Probably best to avoid stepping on that.

Comment: @Gavin Isn't that `Cmd`-`[`? What about `Ctrl`-`[`? Or would that be totally unintuitive for a Mac user? IIRC, `Ctrl` shortcuts are rare on Mac, right?

Comment: Generally, application keyboard shortcuts that use `Ctrl` on other platforms are translated to using `Cmd` on mac. And keyboard shortcuts that don't use  `Cmd` are not nonexistant, but are very rare (outside of terminal programs).

Comment: @Gavin So we could still use `Ctrl`-`[`, or no?

Comment: As a former and occasional Mac user, I think it's a bad idea, but it's not my call.

Comment: `[` is by `AltGr` + `8` on some keyboard layouts (e.g., the one I am using writing this). And `]` is by `AltGr` + `9`. Two modifier keys would be too much. It should work well on other keyboards than the [United States keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#Windows_keyboards) layout.

Answer (score -21):

I really have to disagree with this. As annoying as it can be, the default behavior is designed to allow for mouse-free movement between inputs on the page. Even though everyone has mice now, you still don't want to remove that ability and completely alter the user's experience like that.

Every time I make a new answer or question that uses code, I just copy the 4 spaces and do a Ctrl-V anytime I would normally do a Tab.

If the user wants to create a user script like David Harkness is suggesting, that's great. Each individual user who wants that functionality can do that.

I'm also curious what the effects would be for screen readers and other visually impaired assisters if we remove the native "Tab" functionality from a single box.

Comment: I don't really think that switching input fields (which are only title, body and tags) is more useful than having a tab key indentation functionality (which **every** programmer is used to). Furthermore, the Ctrl+V option is not that efficient, since that when you write code you often have to use your clipboard (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+X) to manipulate the code.

Comment: Yes, *every* programmer is used to that in their IDE, but this is not an IDE and other uses need to be taken into consideration.