# Why is there no auto-indent?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

More often than not, we're pasting code into a SO question or answer, and if/because it's properly indented, ctrl+k or the `{}` button is enough to properly format it.

But once in a while, I write code directly in the question prompt, because it's pseudocode or otherwise something that's not verbatim from an existing program. In these cases it's really annoying to re-type the spaces after every newline.

Of course there are workarounds, like using an external text editor or copying "empty" lines, but it seems strange that this feature doesn't exist. Is there a concrete reason for this, am I doing it wrong, or is the need for it simply smaller than I'd imagine?

Comment: Type it all, then indent it?

Comment: That's typically what I do or hit the code button then ctril+shift for each newline, indent more if needed (inside functions/ifs), then...boom! Posted

Comment: @BradleyDotNET for some reason, I have never thought of that. seems I can't even stand unindented code while writing it :P

Comment: @SillyFreak I'd rather just have "Tab" work so I can do my own indentation farther down the line. Still, the code-snippets I type directly are so short it rarely matters.

Comment: Related: [tab key](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290026/3764814)

Answer (score 0):

How would the editor know you're writing code?

Those four spaces you just typed could be for anything - ASCII art, highlighting the output from a command, etc. The editor would have to know the syntax of all languages in order to recognise that you were typing code to do this.

However, if you assume that the four spaces can put the editor into "code" mode, how do you indicate you've finished writing code and want to return to normal text?

With your scheme you'd have to delete the auto-indention spaces that the system had added.

It's far simpler to ask you, the author to format your code properly outside of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Four spaces at the beginning of a paragraph are by SO's definition code - the only language the editor has to know is SO's highlighting rules.

Comment: re your edit: "delete the auto-indention" is exactly how editors that support it handle it. In case I was not clear: I'm talking about preserving all indentation, not just the initial four. If my last line had 12 spaces, the next will too. If I delete four, the next will have 8 again. That is an improvement over plain typing, at least in my opinion.