# Auto indent new line within a code block

Tags: feature-request, editor

When you type a code, and you press enter, the new line should be filled with x*4 spaces or x tabs. It's not that comfortable to copy tabs/spaces from the previous line, or paste the code to notepad, format it, then paste it back into this editor.

Comment: Closely related: [Markdown editor tab key functionality](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290026/3764814), and the [user script fix](http://stackapps.com/questions/5038/se-like-i-like-it-userscript).

Comment: Also take a look at [Feedback Requested: Code Editor and Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299236).

Comment: It's not so hard to keep 4 spaces copied in clipboard and paste them for each new line...

Comment: @CliffBurton: You can use Google, why is there +1 search bar...? It's not se hard for supporting it, like +20 lines in the js file?

Comment: @CliffBurton That's pretty unreasonable. It may not be hard, but it means that I can't copy/paste anything else without overwriting those spaces in the clipboard.

Comment: To @DavidG and klenium - check [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/2440/increase-decrease-indentation-buttons-for-the-editor) and [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts) They are not _auto indent_ but you can press `Tab` and keep in clipboard whatever you want

Comment: @CliffBurton I'm well aware of those scripts, I just wish (believe?) that the editor should do it by default.

Comment: @CliffBurton: Yeah, I know there're scripts for it, or I could've written my own. But isn't  eg jsfiddle better than stackoverflow + userscript + a plugin that runs it? Why you don't want it to be added to the editor?

Comment: Ehm..I never told I don't want it to be implemented to the editor, I too as soon as I joined this site had tons of ideas to make it better, and mine stackoverflow is full of userscripts, because if I want something I do it by myself. Those scripts are on SE since '12 and I think that all the SE programmers and managers are aware of them, If they had wanted to do it they would have already done ... I think

Comment: The "you can just do more complicated thing X" comments are mind-blowing. How about just writing letters and posting them on the city hall walls to get help with your programming issues - who needs StackOverflow or the internet anyway? This (and many questions relating to indentation with it) is a perfectly valid request and the current editor failure to deal with it appropriately is mind-blowing, considering how many online editors get it right. How about ```?

Answer (score -3):

What I do in VS 2015 is:

1. Select all my code and then press CTRL + SHIFT + TAB so it is indented as far left as possible. If you do not do this, it will have many tabs and then you would need to manually fix each line on stackoverflow.
2. Then copy and paste on StackOverflow edit and select it all and press CTRL + K.

That is the best method I have found so far.

Answer (score -9):

What you do is type your code and then highlight and press ctrl+k. I have done this a couple times and it works perfectly.

Comment: This is the approach I use, which works until it doesn't - such as when I'm adding lines to an existing code block.

Comment: After the first block of code with white space, I have to manually reformat after that. But maybe the flip side is that this inconvenience encourages us to paste as little code as possible so that we focus on the most important content.

Comment: And as soon as you want to present *correctly* indented code, you count 4, 8, 12 spaces. Is is generally enough when pasting code from an IDE even if tabs can give strange results but taking code from a question and adding some line can be tedious

Comment: Why the downvotes?