# Using Code Snippet's JavaScript Tidy option to indent code of other languages

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, tidy

I've been using the JavaScript Tidy option in the Code Snippet popup to edit and indent code in Java posts. I far as I know it works perfectly fine with Java.

[image]

---

- Is it OK to do so?
- What other languages can we indent using the JavaScript Tidy option?
- And finally, can't we come up with a solution to help people to post properly indented code using this?

Comment: None of these are duplicates since you're proposing a workable idea instead of the vague "Should we auto-indent code" that these questions are centered around, but they do have some related content:  [Feedback Requested: Code Editor and Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299236/7795130), [Markdown editor indent and outdent functionality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290026/7795130), and [Auto indent new line within a code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299634/7795130).

Comment: I don't think it worked fine, in your screenshot, lines 8 & 10 have differend indentations

Comment: @Ferrybig I guess this is due to the missing parenthesis, not because it is Java code instead of JS code.

Comment: Good idea. However sometimes fixing the indentation of the code also renders a question invalid, as errors occoured due to bad indentation from a start. Be careful in those situations!

Comment: You're defacing code there, see my comment on the answer. You should not use this for Java. I don't know if there's any language where this would be a good idea, they almost all have cases where the indenter can get it wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**, it is okay to do so. However be sure to:

- If you use the <kbd>Save & insert into post</kbd> button, edit out the snippet and language comments.
- Ensure that you know enough about the language to know the answer to your second question :)

In other words, don't use the JavaScript tidy button on code if you don't know a language's common indentation rules.

As far as your third question, we can't get people to stop using Stack Snippets on languages it doesn't support or even use the code format button correctly, let alone properly indent code when they do get it in correctly.

Help them by doing it yourself and/or give them a link to the [How do I format my posts using Markdown and HTML help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) or [How can I format my code blocks FAQ post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/215552).

Comment: It will probably work acceptably for any language whose syntax is mostly C-like, although it might not conform to the concensus style (e.g. brace location). But now I'm tempted to see how bad it would mangle Lisp. :)

Comment: I strongly recommend not doing this in Java/C#. As you can see in the screenshot in the question, it handles `<` and `>` as greater than/less than comparison operators and adds spaces, so `ArrayList<Integer> myVar` becomes `ArrayList < Integer > myVar`, and that's a bad practice. Imo an indenter that mostly works but sometimes defaces code is worse than one that never works, because you will actually use it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That's not just bad practice, that's actually turning correct code into broken code...

Comment: @anaximander My IDE autocorrects that, but I'm not sure every IDE will.