# Indent and outdent function in editor

Tags: feature-request, editor

### Topic

Extending the source code editor with two buttons for indenting and outdenting source code by 4 characters.

### Problem

Editing long and not well formatted (foreign) source code is sometimes painful. When nested rows are not indented or have a too much indentation spaces it is very cumbersome to move the lines to right or left.

### Feature Request

Having a function for indenting and outdenting source code would be very helpful. This can be done by two additional buttons in the editor header. One for shifting the selected lines to right (indenting), and the other for shifting them to the left (outdenting).

Comment: Even the coliru editor gets this correctly. Though to be fair: The markup editor isn't meant for code editing primarily. I'd appreciate the feature anyways.

Comment: This has ben brought up time and time again, the answer is either "use a userscript" or "edit your code elsewhere then paste it in". I'd love to have some kind of indenting functionality via Tab or editor buttons but seems like nobody in power deems it necessary.

Comment: @SeinopSys: I almost was afraid of it. How can I integrate userscripts? Is there any guidance?

Comment: Have a look at the related questions to the right, [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290026/1344955) has a few

Comment: Sure it'll be fun for those who know how to use it (edit posts), but doubt the newbies or the ones who still don't know how to properly indent will know what those proposed new features will do and how to use them.

Comment: What is so bad about C-k?

Comment: @false: Ctrl-k is for inline code, isn't it?

Comment: And for out-denting

Comment: If there is already an indentation, this indentation is removed. If you want to indent multiple times put a dummy-line with some nonblank character first, mark that too, and you get further indentation

Comment: @false: Ctrl-k or Cmd-k insert backticks on Safari, no outdenting. The indentation isn't changed. I will keep your second suggestion in mind.

Comment: I am using Firefox.

Comment: To be clear: When a selection does not start with four blanks, C-k does indenting. So If you press C-k C-k ... you toggle between these two indentations.

Comment: C-k is mentioned also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). So if you do not have it, that's a bug.

Comment: And: you can click on `{}` for the very same functionality.