# Blockwise indentation

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor, formatting

When I paste code into the text editor, sometimes I have to indent multiple lines to make it look well. So I start to hit the space bar multiple times for each code line until the code is formatted well.

When I select multiple code lines and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> the cursor jumps to the next text field (in my case: Tags).

You can toggle text as code by Crtl+k or button `{}` but this is another function. You can't indent code lines further with Crtl+k.

There should be a function (in form of a button?) to indent all select lines at once.

Edit: This question explains exactly what my feature request is about: [Markdown editor indent and outdent functionality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290026/markdown-editor-indent-and-outdent-functionality?rq=1)

So my question can be closed.

Comment: A simple workaround is to indent the code properly in your native text editor of choice (np++, for example), before copy-pasting it.

Comment: And don't forget the Edit> Blank operation > Tab to space.

Comment: Don't we have both a button and a shortcut (Ctrl+k) for that?

Comment: And one online ide that handles tabs https://stackedit.io/app#

Comment: Ah, so you're talking about blockwise *formatting* of code?

Comment: This is not difficult to understand. OP wants to change the indentation of a selected block of code, by pressing [TAB], beyond the single indent that [Ctrl]+[K] does.

Comment: Guess it's just me being thick then. I stupidly assumed *"make it look well."* meant make it into a code-block.

Comment: @ivarni Ctrl+K doesn't *indent*, it makes toggles selection a being a code block or not. That does include indentation when *making* it into a code block but if you already have one (produced via indentation, rather than tick marks), then it would make the selected lines normal text again - it won't indent, for example, the body of an `if` statement further. If your code block is produced by delimiting it with tick marks, then you'd toggle between the selection having of indentation + *two levels*  l or indentation - *two levels*. At least "two levels" the way SO formats code normally.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, you're the second person to explain it to me now, I get it. It wasn't very clear from the question.

Comment: @user2190035 That edit made it much clearer, thanks.

Comment: "You can't indent code lines further with Crtl+k" - you can, you just have to insert a temporarily character in front of the spaces. Not an ideal solution, but maybe good enough considering the code editing functionality here is not intended to be anything more than basic.

Comment: @Dukeling I'd consider this *less* than basic support. It's a workaround by leveraging an unrelated feature. If we remove the code formatting and just use quote blocks, that would be about the level of the hack you propose.

Comment: Actually with nested lists and that also using indentation, I'd agree indenting multiple times is a core part of editing a post and needs a better solution.